# Binding JSON elements to Java Fields Using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

Is it possible to map a JSON field to a java field in POJO like below-
My JSON is like this-

```
{
  "data": {
    "request": [
      {
        "type": "City",
        "query": "Chennai, India"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I map the field "type" in my POJO below-

```
public class MyClass {
     @JsonProperty("data.request.type") // Can I do something like this?
     private String type;
     // ... getters and setters and other fields
}
```

I don't want to write the POJO as per the incoming JSON, but rather would like to bind elements using qualified names. I googled it but couldn't find any solution.

Is it possible using any library?

Answer (score 0):

No, because `request` is a JSON array and may have multiple elements, so the mapping couldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OGNL library. This library allows you to query JSON and retrieve subnodes. For instance to retrieve type from your JSON you would write `data.request[0].type` and you will get the data. Here is the link to OGNL home: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/